# Plot not shown due to an error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_canvas'

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to show the plots in pop up windows.

This is for plotting a graph.

```
class Sheet:

    def plot_sheet(self):
        fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
        ax.set_xlim([0, self.W]) 
        ax.set_ylim([0, self.L]) 
        recs = []
        for i in range(len(self.rect_list)):
            if self.rect_rotate[i]:
                ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((self.rect_pos[i][0], self.rect_pos[i][1]), self.rect_list[i].l, self.rect_list[i].w,linewidth=3,edgecolor='r'))
            else:
                ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((self.rect_pos[i][0], self.rect_pos[i][1]), self.rect_list[i].w, self.rect_list[i].l,linewidth=3,edgecolor='r'))
        #plt.show()
        return fig
```

This plot_sheets is used because the number of graphs to be shown depends on the inputs.

```
class Indiv:

    def plot_sheets(self):
        for i in range(len(self.sheets)):
            self.sheets[i].plot_sheet()
```

And this is what I did to show the graphs.

```
fig = best.plot_sheets()

dataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = window)
dataPlot.show()
dataPlot.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
```

And running the code, I get this error.

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\sel\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1705, in **call**
>
> return self.func(*args)
>
> File "", line 112, in 
>       proceed_button1 = tk.Button(canvas, text="최적 Component Nesting Plan (제조사용)",font= "calibri 11", command=lambda: cal_culate1())
>
> File "", line 232, in cal_culate1
>       dataPlot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = window)
>
> File "C:\Users\sel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends_backend_tk.py", line 204, in **init**
>       super(FigureCanvasTk, self).**init**(figure)
>
> File "C:\Users\sel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1618, in **init**
>       figure.set_canvas(self)
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_canvas'

How do I recover this error?

Comment: Isn't this the same as your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55707850/error-in-matplotlib-popup-window-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attri)?

Comment: Yes, I created this question because the previous question wasn't well explained I felt.

Comment: why you ask again the same question ? You got the same sugetion in my comment in previous question - you have to use `plot_sheet()` (without `s`) instead of `plot_sheets()` (with `s`). You also got good answer (in previous question) which should help you to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your code that are impossible to address since you don't explain what the desired output should be, and you do not provide the full code.

1. `plot_sheet()` returns a figure instance
2. `plot_sheets()` creates a number of figure instances, but returns none of them (hence returns `None`
3. `FigureCanvasTkAgg()` expects *one* figure instance, but you seem to attempt to provide several, since you want to pass the result of `best.plot_sheets()`